# Prevent stretching of colorbar to width of plot axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

[image]

The plot above has been produced using mpl_toolkits and matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase, because I needed to customise the colormap and colorbar for my discrete dataset, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colorbar
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import random

x = np.arange(1, 1142)
y = np.zeros(len(x))
z = []
for _ in range(len(x)):
    z.append(random.randint(-1, 5))
z = np.array(z)

cmap = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#D52B00', '#AA5500', '#808000', '#55AA00', '#2BD500', '#00FF00'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5], cmap.N)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(z)
lc.set_linewidth(10)

plt.gca().add_collection(lc)

plt.xlim(x.min() - (x.max() * 0.05), x.max() + (x.max() * 0.05))
plt.ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False, labelbottom=False, left=False, labelleft=False)

divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
ax_cb = divider.append_axes('bottom', size="2%", pad=-0.5)
cb = colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_cb, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal', ticks=[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(['-1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
plt.gcf().add_axes(ax_cb)

plt.show()
```

This solution was based on the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html).

My question, is how can I make the colorbar shorter, so that it doesn't stretch across the entire width of the plot axis?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code? Your code is no good for reproducing your plot

Comment: I've edited the question with reproducible code - it will look slightly different to my example because it will generate random data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the divider created via `make_axes_locatable` makes sure the new axes are exactly as large as the one from which it is cut. That is the main aim of this function; but here it's somehow orthorgonal to the desire to have a *different* size.

The solution would be to not use this kind of divider and create the colorbar in the usual fashion via `plt.colorbar` or `fig.colorbar`. This allows to use the arguments `shrink` and `aspect`. Since there is 5% margin on each side of the data, you may want to shrink the colorbar to 90% percent.

```
plt.colorbar(sm, orientation='horizontal', pad=-0.2,  shrink=0.9, aspect=30,
             ticks=[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

x = np.arange(1, 1142)
y = np.zeros(len(x))
z = np.random.randint(-1, 5, size=x.shape)

cmap = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#D52B00', '#AA5500', '#808000', '#55AA00', '#2BD500', '#00FF00'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5], cmap.N)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(z)
lc.set_linewidth(10)

plt.gca().add_collection(lc)

plt.xlim(x.min() - (x.max() * 0.05), x.max() + (x.max() * 0.05))
plt.ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False, labelbottom=False, 
                left=False, labelleft=False)

sm = ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])

plt.colorbar(sm, orientation='horizontal', pad=-0.2,  shrink=0.9, aspect=30,
             ticks=[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I had initially tried something similar, but it was the ScalarMappable function that was the key that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as changing the padding on the colorbar axis,

```
ax_cb = divider.append_axes('bottom', size="2%", pad=0.5)
```

which already looks better,

[image]

A more flexible approach would be to add `subplots_adjust` and `add_axes`. Note, this requires a figure `fig` with axis `ax` to be set up. So your example is,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colorbar
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import random

x = np.arange(1, 1142)
y = np.zeros(len(x))
z = []
for _ in range(len(x)):
    z.append(random.randint(-1, 5))
z = np.array(z)

cmap = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#D52B00', '#AA5500', '#808000', '#55AA00', '#2BD500', '#00FF00'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5], cmap.N)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(z)
lc.set_linewidth(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.add_collection(lc)

plt.xlim(x.min() - (x.max() * 0.05), x.max() + (x.max() * 0.05))
plt.ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False, labelbottom=False, left=False, labelleft=False)

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax_cb = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.11, 0.7, 0.05])

cb = colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_cb, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal', ticks=[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(['-1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
plt.gcf().add_axes(ax_cb)

plt.show()
```